# Anolamy detection in time series data using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, time-series

I am trying to write a python code which detects anomalies in time series data. My input data looks something like this:[image: Input data]
Here, the regions marked in red are anomalies. I want it such that I get the x-coordinate of data-points which are anomalous. So far I have tried a basic if condition (ie if rate < 100, data-point is anomalous) and various statistical techniques like: Mean, Standard deviation, Rolling average with different window sizes etc. However, none of them have worked well. Is there a way to achieve what i want with using some statistical methods? If there are no simple ways to do this, I understand that I have to look to machine learning algorithms. In that case which algorithm would be suitable for my dataset? Thank you.

Comment: @AdrienWehrlé I tried to look for sudden drops in mean and standard deviation. However, the mean and standard deviation drop in the good regions of the data too. So setting a limit on them cuts some good data as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your data comes in lumps, if you are able to distinguish between the lumps (maybe a certain delay between two samples), you can look at the distribution of the samples in the lump. If you know that your rate will never drop below 100, I would start with that, to clean it up a bit,then look at the remaining distribution. The mode value should kind of help identify the "middle", most occuring value. Cutting off everything a certain amount of standard deviations would maybe work to get clean data, but no guarantee that you won't cut off any of your required data.

Edit: you'd have to bin your data before getting the mode.